# Update values from subquery for every single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
update users set first_name = (select firstname from temp_names order by random() limit 1),
    last_name = (select lastname from temp_names order by random() limit 1)
```

Is supposed to get a random row from that temp_names folder, even though it got, but it repeated for every single row it updated, all rows in users had the same first_name value and same last_name value.

How could I make it run the subquery for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Postgres decides to do you a favor by optimizing the subquery and running it only once.  Although Postgres is not the only database that does this, I consider this an error because the subquery depends on a volatile function.  The optimization changes the meaning of the code.

I have found that a correlation clause -- of almost any type -- to the outer query fixes the problem.  For instance, if you have a non-`NULL` id column:

```
update users u
    set first_name = (select firstname from temp_names tn where u.id is not null order by random() limit 1),
        last_name = (select lastname from temp_names where u.id is not null order by random() limit 1);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=288c5106bd55168ac4052326c28ebecd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: isnt there an optimized way to do what i need to do? Because it is taking forever

Comment: @PlayMa256 . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  This question is about why your version of the code does not do what you intend.  If you have a question about performance, that is quite different.  Sample data and table sizes would be very helpful.